# How do I get a date in the format of "mmm-YYYY" given a month and a year in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the following expression in my SSRS template:

```
=UCase(Left(MonthName(Fields!theMonth.Value), 3)) + "-" + Fields!theYear.Value
```

If I take out this bit:

```
+ Fields!theYear.Value
```

The expression works as expected and returns "FEB-" if theMonth is 2.

However SSRS returns an error when I add the year back in.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **&** NOT **+** to concatenate strings.

**+** works much of the time except when mixing types. Since there's an integer, the expression **ass**u**me**s that you are doing math(s).

**&** is used for strings and will convert numbers to strings for the expression.

The expression

```
=UCase(MonthName(5, 1)) + "-" + 2018
```

throws an error.

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   ‘Textbox1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Input string
>   was not in a correct format.

But changing just the + to & does not get an error.

```
=UCase(MonthName(5, 1)) & "-" & 2018
```

[image]

On another note:

MonthName has an optional parameter for abbreviations - just add **,1** after theMonth.Value - `UCase(MonthName(Fields!theMonth.Value, 1), 3)`

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
=UCase(Left(MonthName(Fields!theMonth.Value), 3)) + "-" + UCase(Fields!theYear.Value)
```

Comment: Normally you would use the `CStr` function to convert a number to a string. Looks like `UCase` also works in this situation.